# How can I copy table data from one schema to a table of a different name in a different schema?

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a table called census in my prod schema, and another table called census_backup in my dev schema.

Does TOAD have a GUI feature which will allow me to copy the table data from prod.census to dev.census_backup?

I know that I can copy the table data to the dev schema using "Copy data to another schema," however it seems that that feature will only allow me to copy the data to a table of the same name in the dev schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a existing feature in Toad to do that in a graphical way and being able to choose the target table name.

However, why not using simple sql to do this, such as:

```
create table dev.census_backup as select * from prod.census;
```

?

To do with a user having grants to create tables in dev schema and grant to select in prod schema.